# Can't fetch data from Marvel API status of 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

It's my first time using the Marvel API, but for some reason It's just send me an error status of 401(Unauthorized) in the console. I already included the API key. but still gets the error

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
 import axios from 'axios';

 class Home extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        let api = 'APIHERE'

        axios.get(`https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?apikey=${api}`)
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(error =>{
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
    render(){    
         return(
             <div className = "container">
                <h4>Characters</h4> 
            </div>
         )
     }
 }

 export default Home;
```

Comment: You used the wrong api key if you are getting a 401, use the public key for that endpoint

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a timestamp and a hash-key along with the apiKey for the API call to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install md5 .Second as specified in the api documentation you have to send 3 parameter in order to get authenticated .

ts : timestamp

apikey : public key

hash : md5(ts+publickey+privatekey)

if you are using react-native  : try with hex_md5==>https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-md5

or try to install md5 library instead .